# ordered list formatting 1.1 1.2 1.2.1 but list uses start attribute

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've been trying to format my ordered list into
1 parent one
2 parent two
 1.1 first child
 1.2 second child
   1.2.1 grandchild
   1.2.2 grandchild

I know this can be done using

```
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol > li {
  display: block;
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, '.') '. ';
  counter-increment: item;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, '.') ' ';
}
```

if the list is like this

```
<ol>
 <li>parent one</li>
 <li>
   parent two
   <ol>
     <li>first child</li>
     <li>
       second child
       <ol>
         <li>grand child</li>
         <li>grand child</li>
       </ol>
     </li>
   </ol>
 </li>
</ol>
```

but the list that I am working with (*the data I am not in control) is like this

```
<ol start="6"><li>parent 1</li></ol>
<ol start="7">
 <li>parent 2</li>
 <li>
  parent 3
  <ol>
   <li>
    child
    <ol>
     <li>grand child</li>
     <li>grand child</li>
    </ol>
   </li>
  <ol>
 </li>
</ol>
```

this outputs to

```
1. parent 1
1. parent 2
2. parent 3
      2.1 child
          2.1.1 grand child
          2.1.2 grand child
```

but expected output should be

```
6. parent 1
7. parent 2
8. parent 3
      8.1 child
          8.1.1 grand child
          8.1.2 grand child
```

Comment: So `list-style-none` didn't work?

Comment: ..also the second `ol` example is badly formed. `ol` cannot have `ol` as children. Fix that and your CSS works. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GRpryGV

Comment: oh, my bad, I've fixed it... https://codepen.io/seierherre/pen/MWapKLo
and I've added details, I know it's weird but the data that I am pulling from the cms and I'm only parsing it on the frontend, so I have no control on the form